# ListView scrolling issue in JavaFX2

Tags: javafx

I'm developing a application which has a ListView which contains items which needs complex cell layouts. The cells are in variable heights and some of the cells tends to be larger than the view port height.

But when the ListView is filled with items the scroll thumb tends to resize its self while scrolling, which makes it hard to hold onto the thumb while scrolling. This happens mainly when passing through different size of cells.

This is not a problem in Swing if I create a same kind of a cell render to be used with the JList. This problem is there in JavaFX 2 and JavaFX8 both.

When looking at the VirtualFlow which is responsible for layout of the ListView and handle scrolling, it seems that the scrollbar thumb side (lenghtbar) is calculated based on the cell count and the visible cell count, which is actually a problem when it comes to lists which has variable heights of cells.

So is this the future of the scroll bar behavior for Java FX list views? or is there any solution available for this problem? Or should I try to hide the scrollbar and provide a different user interaction to scroll?

Comment: It sounds like a bug - you could have a look at [jira](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22scrollbar%22) to see if it has already been reported and if not report it with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is already reported under https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25059 and fixed in Java8 upto some extend. So if this fix is needed on JavaFx2 we have to backport the changes under commit http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/controls/rt/rev/81cc13fe6f96

To get this changes in JavaFX 2.2 you need to apply the required changes on to FX2.2 VirtualFlow.java class and load those changes before the jfxrt.jar is loaded. Another approach is if you don't like to mess up with the jfxrt classes is to have you own ListView which uses your own Skin and the patched VirtualFlow version may be with a different name. But this might require lot of customization compared to first solution.

More approaches are welcome :).